# admin login in Magento redirect to other project

Tags: php, magento

I am facing problem while logging into magento admin.Before I had a project named magento which is working perfectly but after that I have create a new project named magento_test and the database named magento_test,but after installing magento_test project the tables are not created under magento_test database but admin login is working correctly.Then I have deleted both the project and database named magento_test.But while logging in to my existing magento project,instead of redirecting to magento project its redirecting to magento_test project which was already deleted,So I am unable to access my admin  and user section.

As I am a beginner in magento so please guide me to get through this problem,So I will be grateful to you.

Comment: You cannot just copy (or rename) the database and folder and expect it to perform perfect on another domain. Check the `core_config_data` database table for the last domainname and update your new database with the new domainname... For starters... The rest depends on your installation and server settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magento url' redirect is guided by the core_config_data fields where path is  like "%web/unsecure/base_url%" and "web/secure/base_url" , please check these fileds.

Comment: Thanks miwata for your replay.But I changed both row but after that it redirect to magento_test project.

Comment: yes it's done but after clear /var/cache and /var/session. Again Thanks mr miwata